# How to convert this ER diagram to relational schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

[image: **enter image description here**]

How can we convert Many to one relationship contains Multi valued attribute into relational schema
I thought of doing schedule as table having the primary key of sport only
or
having primary key of both Sports & coach
I am confused can anyone help ?

Comment: http://www.fe.up.pt/~jmoreira/wwwsi/2000-01/eerm.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In short, you'll need to:

1. Describe what you're trying to model (e.g. "a collection of sports, with teams, that have coaches, and play matches on certain days and times"). This will come from your requirements.
2. Identify your entities (usually the "nouns").
3. Work out how they are related to each other (e.g. does a team have a single sport or multiple sports? Can a coach be a coach of more than one team?)
4. Draw your ER diagram using this knowledge, representing each of the entities as how they should be related (e.g. one to one, one to many, many to many).
5. If there are any many-to-many relationships, they will need a joining table

Hope that helps. I can elaborate further if you are not sure on any of this.